# Trying to get property of non-object (2)

Tags: php

I keep getting this errror:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

The problem is with a SQL date field called 'sterfdatum' when this field in my DB is filled in with for example '1988-12-01 15:13:14'. Then there is no problem with my code. But when field is like this '0000-00-00 00:00:00', and I try to get this out from my DB the error is showed.

this is my model:

```
<?php

public function get_artist($last_name = NULL , $front_name = NULL, $language = 'nl')
    {
        // infoNL as language so language can be used in the View file
        if($language == 'nl')
        {
            $this->db->select('naam, voornaam, geboortedatum, geboorteplaats, foto, infoNL as language, sterfdatum')
                 ->from('kunstenaar')
                 ->where('naam', $last_name)
                 ->where('voornaam', $front_name)
                 ->limit(1);

            return $this->db->get()->row();
        }
        elseif($language == 'en')
        {
            $this->db->select('naam, voornaam, geboortedatum, geboorteplaats, foto, infoEN as language, sterfdatum')
                 ->from('kunstenaar')
                 ->where('naam', $last_name)
                 ->where('voornaam', $front_name)
                 ->limit(1);

            return $this->db->get()->row();
        }

    }
```

In my view I have this

```
if($artist->sterfdatum != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
       {
           $birthYear = date('Y', strtotime($artist->geboortedatum));
           $dieYear = date('Y', strtotime($artist->sterfdatum));

       }
$artist->sterfdatum != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' And here is the problem.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($artist->sterfdatum) && $artist->sterfdatum != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') { 
$birthYear = date('Y', strtotime($artist->geboortedatum)); 
$dieYear = date('Y', strtotime($artist->sterfdatum));
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it seems that you're assigning a variable artist that is not an object to your view.

This error probably occurs when no match for your query are found in your database.

Assuming that your method get_artist() returns a NULL, you should try something like this :

```
if(isset($artist))
{
    if($artist->sterfdatum != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    {
        $birthYear = date('Y', strtotime($artist->geboortedatum));
        $dieYear = date('Y', strtotime($artist->sterfdatum));
    }
}
```

However you should look what's the value in $artist when the error occurs to make the correct test for it.

Hope it helps you.